# How can I compile with Guile 2.0 on Homebrew?

Tags: macos, homebrew, guile

I am trying to compile a project with Homebrew on Mac OSX 10.14 Mojave. I have guile 2.2.x:

```
guile --version
guile (GNU Guile) 2.2.6
```

but the project does not support guile 2.2, only 2.0. How can I install guile 2.0 with Homebrew, and how can I instruct the system to use it in compilation?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently as of this date, [Guile 2.0 isn't available on Homebrew](https://discourse.brew.sh/t/is-legacy-guile-2-0-available-with-homebrew/5287). Just putting this up for those who may be searching.